# c++ char*, string pointer, and strcmp question

Tags: c++, string, pointers, strcmp

This question is composed of two parts:

Part 1
In the below code, I get this error when I try to compile: 
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std;

bool check_input(char &buysell) {
    char const* buy = "b";
    char const* sell = 's'; //error here

    if (strcmp(cp, buy)!=0) or (strcmp(cp, sell)!=0) return false;  //errors out because of error above

    return true; 
}

int main() {
     cout << "!!!Hello once more" << endl; // prints !!!Hello once more

     string user_order;

     string done= "done trading";

     char buysell;

     while(user_order.compare(done) != 0) {
         cout << "enter order"<< endl;
         getline(cin, user_order);
         stringstream lineStream(user_order);
         lineStream >>   buysell;
         check_input(buysell);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why that is. I want a pointer to a char that holds the value of b and another pointer that points to a char that holds the value of s so strcmp would work.

I don't understand the difference between these two:

```
char const* buy = "b"; 
char const* sell = 's'; //error here : error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

buy should be a pointer to a string literal of 'b NULL' and sell should be a pointer to just a char literal 's'. Why does the string literal work and the char literal doesn't work? Isn't it suppose to be working with chars?

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Part 2:
After I changed s to use double quotes the code still errors out on the next line:

```
bool check_input(char &buysell) {
    char const* buy = "b";
    char const* sell = "s";

    if (strcmp(buysell, buy)!=0) or (strcmp(buysell, sell)!=0) return false;  //error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

    return true; 
}
```

So I think buy and sell are points pointing to a memory that holds bNULL and sNULL. But buysell is a straight char. Does this mean I need to convert buysell into a string before I do a compare?

Thanks

Comment: `return buysell == 'b' || buysell == 's';` You are way over-complicating it. `strcmp` is for comparing strings - NUL-terminated sequences of characters. You don't have one of those, you just have a single character.

Comment: `bool check_input(char &buysell)` <-- there is no reason to pass `buysell` by reference. This adds pointless indirection. You only need to pass by reference in a few cases: (1) the referent is mutated, and it's not here, or (2) making a copy of the referent would be very expensive, and that's not the case here either, or (3) making a copy of the referent is prohibited.

Comment: Actually, your question is pretty good. There is no logical reason that a string literal is a chunk of initialized static memory but a char literal is not. Well observed. (The reason *has* to do with the fact that chars can easily be passed by value in C/C++ and thus can translate to simple "immediate values" in assembler, while an array cannot. (Its *address* can, and is, though. In order to have a meaningful address you have to have persistent memory, which is why C (and hence C++) defined character string literals the way they do.)

Comment: Both parameters to `strcmp()` are `const char *`? What is so unclear about a compilation error as a result, unless this is the case? Unlike other programming languages, C++ is strongly-typed: if something has to be a particular type, it must be, no exceptions. A compilation error results unless there's an implicit or an explicit conversion rule from one type to another. There are no conversion rules from a `char` to a `const char *`, or vice versa. That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But you see the OP's logic? `"abc"`  is a literal sequence of three characters in the source code, surrounded by delimiters. That sequence translates to a sequence of characters in the program's memory (4, because of the implicit 0 byte). `'a'` is a sequence of one character in the source code, surrounded by delimiters. It is a very similar construct. But it does not at all translate into a character in memory. The semantics of a character string literal --  namely that it is a special notation for an array -- cannot be inferred from notation.

Comment: Notice that "a" is a sequence of characters with a single character in it. That is, the type of "a" is a char array and since C arrays like to degenerate to pointers, you get a `char *`. On the other hand, 'a' is NOT an array. It is simply a `char`.
That explains why you get an error in `char const* sell = 's';`